# Apollo (GraphQL) fetch more than one element in a query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Can I fetch more than one element in a GraphQL query? I have many products list data and I want to fetch, for example, three products in my component. I have an array of needed product IDs, can I pass it to query? This is my query for one product:

```
query ProductInCartQuery($id: ID!){
  Product(id: $id) { 
   id
   name
   price
 }
}
```

But I don't think I can just put it in a function and execute it for example three times for three products.

Comment: Please edit your post to contain your schema code.

Comment: Sure you can...

Comment: How? I added my query in edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's common and very useful to offer two kind of queries for every type you have:

1. a query to fetch a single node with an `id` or other unique fields, that's in your case `Product` (you already have this).
2. a query to fetch many nodes depending on different filter conditions, let's call it `allProducts`.

Then you have two options to fetch multiple products in one query.

First, you can use the `Product` query multiple times and use [GraphQL Aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases) to avoid a name clash in the response data:

```
query ProductInCartQuery($firstId: ID!, $secondId: ID!){
  firstProduct: Product(id: $firstId) { 
    id
    ... ProductInfo
  }

  secondProduct: Product(id: $secondId) { 
    id
    ... ProductInfo
  }

  fragment ProductInfo on Product {
    name
    price
  }
}
```

You could build this query string dynamically depending on the ids you want to query. However, it's probably best to use the `allProducts` query with the necessary filter setup if the number of differents ids is dynamic:

```
query filteredProducts($ids: [ID!]!) {
  allProducts(filter: {
    id_in: $ids
  }) {
    ... ProductInfo
  }
}

fragment ProductInfo on Product {
  name
  price
}
```

You can try it out yourself in [this GraphQL Playground](https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/cj3omdwtfhqil0198icmyw9k5?query=query%20ProductInCartQuery%20%7B%0A%20%20firstProduct%3A%20Product(id%3A%20%22cj3omj91a6eli0198aqe0d9j3%22)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20...%20ProductInfo%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20secondProduct%3A%20Product(id%3A%20%22cj3omjmxh5ddi0197ndrr9t1v%22)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20...%20ProductInfo%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aquery%20filteredProducts%20%7B%0A%20%20allProducts(filter%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id_in%3A%20%5B%22cj3omj91a6eli0198aqe0d9j3%22%2C%20%22cj3omjmxh5ddi0197ndrr9t1v%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...%20ProductInfo%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afragment%20ProductInfo%20on%20Product%20%7B%0A%20%20id%0A%20%20name%0A%20%20price%0A%7D%0A%0A) I prepared for you. More background information can be found [in this article](https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/designing-powerful-apis-with-graphql-query-parameters-aing7uech3/).

Comment: Thanks! Filter parameter was exactly this what I needed ;)

Answer (score 2):

For adding the product ids to the query you could define a `input` type. See the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/sogko/graphql-schema-language-cheat-sheet).

So the query on the client could look like:

```js
query ProductsInCartQuery($productIds: ProductIds!) {
  Products(productIds: $productIds) {
    id
    name
    price
  }
}
```

On the server you define the schema with the `input` type as follows:

```js
input ProductIds {
  ids: [ID!]
}

type Query {
  Products(productIds: ProductIds!) {
    id
    name
    price
  }
}

schema {
  query: Query
}
```